# querySelector does not seem to find elements inside ng-container

Tags: html, web, dart, angular-dart

I am developing a web application using angular dart.

I am trying to find a 'div' element inside the component using document.querySelector() and I am trying to modify(add some content to) its body.

But it doesn't seem to find the 'div' element.

Here is my html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
  <ng-container *ngIf="item.canShowChart">
    <div [id]="item.elementID" class="chart"></div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Here is my component method which tries to modify the 'div':

```
  void drawChart() {
    for (final item in list) {
      if (!item.canShowChart) {
        continue;
      }
      final DivElement _container = document.querySelector('#' + item.elementID);
      print(_container);
    }
  }
```

It always prints the '_container' as 'null'

I tried removing the ng-container and having only the 'div' in the page like below and it seems to work!.

```
<div [id]="item.elementID" class="chart"></div>
```

What is the problem?

TIA.

Comment: You'll probably be better off doing that inside the template. What exactly do you want to do to that div?

Comment: @mbojko I am trying to draw a pie chart inside the container:  
```
final DivElement _container = document.querySelector('#' + item.elementID);
PieChart(_container).draw(result.chartData, chartDrawingOptions);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a separate component, let's call it `app-chart`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of list">
  <app-chart *ngIf="item.canShowChart" [item]="item">
  </app-chart>
</ng-container>
```

In the AppChartComponent declare necessary input(s), and inject ElementRef in the constructor:

```
@Input() item: any;
constructor(private ref: ElementRef) {}
```

`this.ref.nativeElement` is how you can access the DOM element from inside.

Comment: But is there a way to achieve this using just one component?

Comment: Nice.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Need to access the form element and now can do `this.ref.nativeElement.querySelector('form')`

Answer (score 6):

It is not working because as at the time you used 'querySelectorAll', angular had not loaded ng-container to the DOM yet. You should put your code in the 'AfterViewChecked' lifecycle hook.

```
export class ImageModalComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked{
  //AfterViewChecked
  ngAfterViewChecked {
    void drawChart() {
    for (final item in list) {
      if (!item.canShowChart) {
        continue;
      }
      final DivElement _container = document.querySelector('#' + item.elementID);
      print(_container);
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Make sure to import 'AfterViewChecked' like so;

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use `querySelector` to find elements in your template. Angular and DOM are two seperate paradigms and you should not mix them.

To find an element in your template, use a reference to an element.

```
<div #chartContainer class="chart"></div>
```

Then you can reference the `div` from your code.

See https://itnext.io/working-with-angular-5-template-reference-variable-e5aa59fb9af for an explanation.

Comment: It is important to note that I am iterating a list (see a 'ngFor' on the top). So, each div element reference name must be unique across the list . How to go about this?

Comment: But what if the element we are querying for is inside a component?

Answer (score 0):

AfterViewChecked not worked. Use AfterViewInit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).